# Rewrite views.py without using locals()

Tags: python, django, view

I have the following template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "=//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html land="en">
<head>
    <title>Some Meta Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        {% for key,values in meta %}
        <li> {{ key }}, {{ values }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

And corresponding views.py:

```
def display_meta(request):
    meta = request.META.items()
    metadata = []
    for k,v in meta:
        key = k
        values = v 
    return render_to_response('meta.html', locals())
```

How do I re-write the function above such that it doesn't use `locals()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view can just be:

```
def display_meta(request):
    meta = request.META.items()
    return render_to_response('meta.html', {"meta": meta})
```

Since you'll have to iterate meta to generate the template you don't have to do it in the view.  Also the second argument of render_to_response can be a dictionary of keys to add into the template context.